# Кавычки при необычном употреблении слова

Tags: пунктуация

Где можно почитать о постановке кавычек при необычном употреблении слова? Выделяются ли кавычками неологизмы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь можно почитать:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1

> Выделяются ли кавычками неологизмы?

«Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке» Д. Э. Розенталя указывает, что кавычками выделяются:
1) слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, на которые автор хочет обратить внимание;
2) слова, употребленные в особом, необычном значении;
3) слова, представляющие собой малоизвестные термины;
4) **слова устарелые или, наоборот, совсем новые, если подчеркивается эта их особенность**.